# How to release a new version on GitHub?

Tags: git, github

We weren’t able to create the release for you. Please help me correct the errors below.

[image]

Can anyone help me creating releases on GitHub?

Comment: It looks like you haven't specified a tag...?

Comment: @canton7 even if made the tag, it doesn't tell me the error.

Comment: the problem has been solved by creating a tag using the command line

Comment: Yes, the tag has to exist before you create a release. The fact that it's not showing you a proper error is a GitHub problem which we can't solve, I recommend raising this with GitHub

Comment: why nobody says how to create tag:) it's done using git command. so 

1) create tag using `git tag 0.0.1` <-- put your own tag instead of 0.0.1
2)  git push origin --tags
3) then go to github and make a release with this tag

Answer (score 20):

we have to "Create a tag" first before we can publish. 
 type tag name and hit create new tag button on the dropdown to create one

[image]

It feels like preety bad ui/ux from github's part, the error message says "invalid" tag, and what it actually means is we need to type and hit "create new tag" and then select the tag to be able to use it. Jesus!

Comment: Indeed, weirdly designed still to this day. Thank you for the answer, took me a while to realize.

Answer (score 12):

In **Tag version** textbox, you type your version number started by `v`, for example `v1.0.0` .

See example at:

https://github.com/donhuvy/QuanLySinhVien/releases/tag/v1.0.0

[image]

[image]

Comment: Didn't expect that from Github! It's not user-friendly at all.

Answer (score 3):

You just have to enter the non existing tag in the selection dropdown and, it will let you create it

Answer (score 1):

Note there is a delta between "**Create a tag"** and the "**Title**".
So if you just fill in the title, then it won't work. Have to also create a tag. (It doesn't assume the title is the tag).

[image]